# For loop returns repeating NA values

Tags: r

I want to use this for loop to determine the profit that results from each of the "bids" that I have placed in my `MillerBids` vector.  The output needs to be a vector with 10 elements. The problem is that this code only returns repeating NA values.

I assume the error is either somewhere in my indexing or resetting my variables and vectors.  Those are two things I find hard to understand when working with more complicated loops.

```
library(triangle)

MillerBids = c(10500,11000,11500,12000,12500,13000,13500,14000,14500,15000)

CostToBid = 350
ProjCost = 10000
Comps = 4

MillerProfs = c()
for (MillerBid in MillerBids) {
  CompBids = c()
  MillerProf = 0
  for (Comp in 1:Comps) 
    CompBids[Comp] = MillerBid * rtriangle(1, a=0.9, b=1.8, c=1.3)
  MinComp = min(CompBids)
  if (MillerBid < MinComp) {
    MillerProf = MillerBid - (CostToBid + ProjCost)
  } else { 
    MillerProf = 0 - CostToBid 
  }
  MillerProfs[MillerBid] = MillerProf
}
MillerProfs
```

returns: `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`... several thousand times

I'm aware of the benefits to using the `apply()` family of functions, but for this particular instance I need to use this for loop,  and I also need to improve my understanding of them.

As I said the goal is to have `MillerProfs` be a vector with 10 elements, each being a profit number relating to the values in `MillerBids`.

Comment: The problem is at `MillerProfs[MillerBid] = MillerProf` - you're using `MillerBid` as the index to the vector `MillerProfs`, so it's ultimately creating a vector of length 15000, mostly NAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code when you are doing

```
MillerProfs[MillerBid] = MillerProf
```

in the first iteration `MillerBid` value was 10500 the first value in the vector `MillerBids` hence, the calculated value (`MillerProf`) was stored at that index and all the middle values were turned to NA.

It's like doing

```
x = numeric()
x[5] = 10
x
#[1] NA NA NA NA 10
```

Similarly, in your case all the first 10499 values were `NA` and you had your actual value stored at 10500 index. Same thing happened with rest of the iterations.

Instead try looping over it's index

```
library(triangle)

MillerProfs <- numeric(length(MillerBids))

for (i in seq_along(MillerBids)) {
   CompBids = 0
   MillerProf = 0
   for (Comp in 1:Comps) 
      CompBids[Comp] = MillerBids[i] * rtriangle(1, a=0.9, b=1.8, c=1.3)
   MinComp = min(CompBids)
   if (MillerBids[i] < MinComp) {
     MillerProf = MillerBids[i] - (CostToBid + ProjCost)
  } else { 
      MillerProf = 0 - CostToBid 
  }
  MillerProfs[i] = MillerProf
}


MillerProfs
# [1]  150  650 1150 1650 2150 2650 3150 3650 4150 4650
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the ```seq_along()``` function, that fixed the loop.  I did have to make one change to your code however.  In the conditional part of the if statement ```MillerBid``` is missing the ```[i]```